# I need libdb4.2 in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04

The bottom line is, I want to install qtstalker_0.32-1_i386, which is a very promising commodity and stock charting platform for linux on sourceforge.net. in the install it says libdb4.2 is missing and is a dependency,

I can't seem to find libdb4.2 anywhere for Ubuntu, I installed libdb-dev but that didn't seem to help. I'm running Ubuntu Mate 15.04, great thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: Try here: http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/ruby-bdb/libdb4.2-ruby1.8_0.6.5-7build1_all.deb

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to install `qtstalker_0.32-1_i386` in Vivid. It might work, but after a few steps you're in a hell of unfulfillable dependencies. The reason is, the package is simply too old. Many libraries or packages can not be installed on your system or only with considerable effort.

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.